# How to pass mat4 array to shader in opengl es 2 in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo

Hi this is my first post here :)
I working on Android 2.3 OpenGL ES 2 2D game engine. I try to improve performance by building one big VBO instead of drawing sprite one by one. I using batching to draw 32 sprites at once.

This is my vertex shader definition:

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix[32];
```

When I use client side memory

```
for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    mvpBuffor.put(models[k], 0, models[k].length);
mvpBuffor.position(0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, m, false, mvpBuffor);
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m * VERTEX_PER_SPRITE);
```

and this works very good 
but when I try to use VBO

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, batch.mvpBufferIndex);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mMVPMatrixHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mMVPMatrixHandle, MVP_SIZE * BATCHSIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

I get error code 1281

Any one knows how to pass array of mat4 uniform to vertex shader ?

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you read this [page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man), it should be something like:

```
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(<handle>, <number of matrices>, <transposed?>, <array of matrices>);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your shader's still declaring the mvpMatrix as uniform

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix[32];

yet you're trying to pass it in as an attribute:

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mMVPMatrixHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mMVPMatrixHandle, MVP_SIZE * BATCHSIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in GLES on mobiles uniform arrays are broken
https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176674-Uniform-arrays-in-OpenGLES

Comment: Not broken in GLES, the spec is clear: "the location of the first element of an array can be retrieved by using the name of the array, or by using the name appended by "[0]".". 
If JoshKlint's assertions in that thread are true (and I imagine they were at the time of writing). Then there were different bugs on both iOS and Galaxy Tab drivers 5 years ago.